# Haskell : How to obtain a list of 2^i , where i is nature number and 2^i are all smaller than a given number?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, fold

I tried the list comprehension `[2^i | i<-[1..], 2^i<34]` , but I got something strange from GHCi :

```
Prelude> [2^i | i<-[1..], 2^i<34]
[2,4,8,16,32
```

Then I tried `filter (<34) [2^i | i<-[1..] ]` , and I get the same result .

My original purpose is to use this in something like `while` loop , where we don't know when to stop the loop .

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell doesn't know that `2^i >= 34` is implied by `i > C` for some value `C`. It will keep trying every value in the (infinite) iterator to see if there are any more values that meet the condition.

You can help Haskell out by using `takeWhile` on an infinite list instead of using a guard to filter the infinite list.

```
> takeWhile (< 34) [2^i | i <- [1..]]
[2,4,8,16,32]
```